# If statement Stata

Tags: if-statement, stata

I'm trying to build the following if statement in Stata:
I want Stata to restrict my sample with the following conditions `keep if distance > 50 & distance < 60` **but only if** the binary variable `category = 0`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: See `help if` and `help operators` for introductory advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra condition in your if-statement.

```
keep if category == 1 | (category == 0 & distance > 50 & distance < 60)
```

Comment: Thank you but this would drop the category = 1 observations, which I need to keep.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you want to restrict the sample to all observations that are category 0 and are also between 50 and 60 in distance, that is:

```
keep if (category == 0 & distance > 50 & distance < 60)
```

Comment: No, because the OP added a complication to their question in a comment on the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to maintain both types of observations in your dataset I recommend you create a new dummy variable called `restricted_sample`. After that, you could calculate statistics with both categories or each of them separately. You can create this variable according to your requirements in the following way:

```
gen restricted_sample = 1 if category == 0 & distance > 50 & distance < 60 & !missing(distance) & !missing(category) 
replace restricted_sample = 0 if restricted_sample == .& !missing(distance) & !missing(category)
```

Then you can obtain statistics considering the different subgroups:

```
* All 
sum distance

* For each group
sum distance if restricted_sample == 1
sum distance if restricted_sample == 0
```

You can test the code with the following dataset. This dataset includes some missing values also.

```
clear all 
set obs 100
gen distance = runiform(1,100)
gen category = 1 if _n > 50
replace category = 0 if _n < 50 
replace distance = . if mod(_n, 7) == 0
replace category = . if mod(_n, 13) == 0
```

I hope it will be useful for you.